# How I can overlay video onto another video start from 2 second to 4 second?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need overlay video onto another video start from 2 second to 4 second.

I use ffmpeg for overlaying video onto another video for this command
`ffmpeg -i tmp/test_screen_1672755242397.mp4 -vf "movie=tmp/test_camera_1672755249551.mp4, scale=250: -1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay =10: 10 [out]" completed.mp4`
But video `test_camera_1672755249551` must be to star from 2 second and end to 4 second. What I need to add in command for result?

Comment: overlay=enable='between(t,2,4)'

Comment: `ffmpeg -i tmp/test_screen_1672755242397.mp4 -vf "movie=tmp/test_camera_1672755249551.mp4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB, scale=250: -1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay =10: 10:enable='between(t\,2,4)' [out]" completed.mp4`

should work to delay the overlay